# php error function for drop down selection validation user type match

Tags: php, function, drop-down-menu

need help with an error function for a login form. 
the login obviously asks for username/password. but a feature i added is the roletype/ usertype that needs to be selected. what i wanna achieve is that the user selected the proper role in accordance to the database(admin, employee, etc). i need help with the last error function in the if statement.

If the role doesn't match the role in the database attached to the user, print an error message saying this role does not match the user

```
//login existing user from login page 
if (isset($_POST['login'])) 
{
$username   = $_POST['username'];
$password   = $_POST['password'];
$role       = $_POST['role'];

//confirm that fields are filled in correctly
if(empty($username))
{
    array_push($errors, "Username is required*"); 
}
if(empty($password))
{
    array_push($errors, "Password is required*");
}
if($_POST['role'] != $role)
{
    array_push($errors, "Role is incorrect");
}
```

Comment: Have you done the database query to fetch the user's role to then compare to the user submitted value?

Comment: May i have an example for that query?

Comment: If you are able to provide and example of your DB schema, then it is a possibility.